# Question about the time-ordered exponential operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, mathematics, time-evolution

I learned that a unitary matrix generated by time-dependent Hamiltonians is written down as

\begin{equation}
U(t) = \mathcal{T}\exp\Big(-i\int_0^t H(t') dt' \Big),\tag{1}
\end{equation} where $\mathcal{T}\exp$ is the time-ordered exponential operator.

My question is: is the $k$th power of the unitary operator $$U^k(t) = \mathcal{T}\exp\Big(-i\int_0^t kH(t') dt' \Big)~?\tag{2}$$

Comment: Have you tried a simple example with three time points?

Comment: Also, don't forget that the notation of a "time-ordered exponential" is just a *notational convenience*. It *must* be taken to mean the power series of time-ordered operators. The "time-ordering operator" is not a linear operator and we are *not* "applying it" linearly to each term in an expansion of an exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: No, OP's eq. (2) does not necessarily hold.

*Counterexample.* Take e.g.
$$H(t)~=~A~ \delta(t-\frac{1}{3})~+~B~ \delta(t-\frac{2}{3}), $$
where the operators $A$ and $B$ do not commute: $[A,B]\neq 0$. Then
$$ T\exp\left[2\int_0^1\! dt~H(t)\right]~=~e^{2B}e^{2A},$$
while
$$ T\left[\exp\int_0^1\! dt~H(t)\right]~ T\left[\exp\int_0^1\! dt~H(t)\right]~=~e^Be^Ae^Be^A.$$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Actually I confronted a small confusion while rethinking about this problem after looking at your answer. Since the superoperator $\text{ad}_{H(t)}$ commutes with itself for any choice of $H(t)$, isn't the following equality hold: $T \exp(-i \int_0^T \text{ad}_{2H(t)} dt) = T\exp(-i \int_0^T \text{ad}_{H(t)} dt) T\exp(-i \int_0^T \text{ad}_{H(t)} dt) = \mathcal{U} \circ \mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is the superoperator, i.e. $\mathcal{U}(\rho) = U \rho U^\dagger$?. This contradicts to your answer. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For time dependent Hamiltonian $U$ does not necessarily have the time translation symmetry. You should write $U(t,t')$ and then I don't really know what $U^k$ represents.

For time independent Hamiltonian $U^k(t) = U(kt)$ is just a time propagation by $kt$ due to the group structure of $U$ operators. On the other hand
$ U(kt) = \mathcal T \exp\left(-i \int_0^{kt} H dt'\right) = \mathcal T \exp\left(-i \int_0^{t} k H dt''\right)$

which is what you asked for.

Comment: If the Hamiltonian is not time dependent the time ordering is the identity and everything is trivial….

Comment: Yeah, you're right